# Kubuntu 12.04 keyboard + mouse do not respond

Tags: keyboard, mouse, kde, uefi, kde4

I just installed Kubuntu 12.04 amd-64. When I login the mouse, moves but the clicks appear to be random (some are accepted and some are not) and the same happens with the keystrokes. This makes the system utterly unusable.

The strange things is that I'm writing this from the live USB from which I installed the system and both work just fine.

I should mention I had issues getting the system to boot-up after installation due to my board's UEFI. I got around that by starting the live USB in not-UEFI mode.

**EDIT**: I gave up and installed Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and managed to fix it by reinstalling the OS (64-bit), but this time without installing third party software and downloading updates. I then installed the the graphics driver (NVIDIA) under Systems and Muon to update the system.

Comment: Same problem here, same solution: If 'install third party software' is enabled during the installation, mouse clicks do not work most of the time once in KDE. If it is disabled, things seem to work ok.